# Link to search help?

Tags: support, status-completed, search, hyperlinks, faq-update-request

Where's the link to the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=)? Shouldn't it be in the faq?
I came to it by accident when I hit enter on an empty search.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's also in the sidebar of every search result page, but that's a good idea too!

edit: added.

> #### Are there any search options?
>
> Indeed there are. Advanced Super Ninja Search Options no less. [Visit the search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) to see them … but you must first snatch this pebble from my hand, grasshopper.

Comment: Most people would use site search, look in the faq or expect a help link near the action element to find help. None of these are present. Plus, and I assume for many others as well, my eyes tend to ignore non navigational sidebars because they usually contain ads, tag clouds, statistics and non important data.

Comment: +1 for being so flexible to new input.