# Put the search tips in the FAQ

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The link to search tips shows up only AFTER you do a search. Plus it's easily missed because when one does a search, one's eyes automatically go to the search result area. The right column by habit is ignored too because it usually has irrelevant data: ads, tag clouds, stats ..etc.

Anything that's used heavily on a site should be put in the FAQ page and that includes search. I have to do a dummy search to get the link to the search tips link. I suppose I can bookmark it.

BTW, why does search on 'user' does not bring up the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hit `<ENTER>` in the search box to get the help screen.

I'm always clicking on the search icon ([alt text http://sstatic.net/mso/Img/search.png](http://sstatic.net/mso/Img/search.png)) expecting it to bring up the search help, but that doesn't work.

Comment: +1 because the non-functional icon bothers me too.

Comment: Hello -- I'm Jonathan Sampson...I clicked the icon too :(

Comment: @jonathan ok, I removed the image since it was confusing.

Comment: @jeff You didn't need to remove it - I think it looked good aesthetically up there.

Comment: The empty search is a good tip. You see, things like this are not mentioned anywhere and few people know this stuff. If the FAQ page has a link to the search tips it helps. Sometimes I read a faq page just to see if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is completed and was requested here:

[Link to search help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39328/link-to-search-help)